# How to restrict Wordpress Admin access just to one or two machines

Tags: wordpress, ssl

How its possible to restrict and limit the access to the wordpress Admin (even after login), just to one or two machines.
How could I create "manually" a certification, existing on one computer, that will be checked for the access to my admin page?

Answer (score 0):

You can create an `.htaccess` file in the /wp-admin folder to restrict access by IP or hostname. In the `.htaccess` file, add the following:

```
<LIMIT GET>
order deny,allow
deny from all
allow from [xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx]
allow from [host.domain.com]
</LIMIT>
```

You can also create an `.htpasswd` file to use BASIC authentication that is outside of Wordpress authentication. Create the file by running:

```
htpasswd -c .htpasswd [username]
```

Where [username] is the username you would like to create, it will prompt for a password. To add additional users, omit the `-c` (this flag creates a new file). Once you have created your .htpasswd file, reference it in the `.htaccess` file like so:

```
<LIMIT GET>
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Wordpress Admin"
AuthUserFile /path/to/authfile/.htpasswd
Require valid-user
</LIMIT>
```

Comment: But the IP of the computer will change!

Comment: Will they have a consistent hostname? You can also `Allow from [hostname]`.

Answer (score 0):

You could use client-certificate authentication to restrict access to that part of the site. (For usability, it's probably better to request the certificate via renegotiation, within a directory/location directive, and not for the entire host.)

The CA for the client certificate doesn't have to be related to the server certificate's CA, so you could have your own small CA. (There are tools to help you with this, for example, OpenSSL's `CA.pl` or TinyCA.)

You would need to issue certificates for the browsers you want to allow for these connections. You can also map certain Subject DNs to certain user names (using `FakeBasicAuth` authentication) and use this for authorisation. There are examples here: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/ssl/ssl_howto.html#accesscontrol

You could leave the usage of the private keys on these browser not password-protected (although it's not generally a good idea), so anyone use those machines could have access in this way (if that's what you're trying to do). It's certainly better to protect them with a password (e.g. master security password in Firefox), so that you know it's the right user of the machine too. You may want to look into the non-exportable private key options of IE for this, so that even the legitimate user can't export the private key (at least without some degree of difficulty).